# Issue in searching from associative array on the basis of particular field

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-5.5

I have written below lines of code for grabbing number of beds of a specific room  of hostel

```
 $RoomsArray = array_column($RoomsDetails->jsonSerialize(), 'NumberOfBeds');
 $FoundNumberOfBeds = array_search('f2937f76-05d0-9725-06fc-37cf061a31c6', $RoomsArray);
 $json_string = json_encode($RoomsDetails->jsonSerialize(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 var_dump($FoundNumberOfBeds);
```

It shows `bool(false)`

The desired output should be 2

`$RoomsDetails->jsonSerialize()` contains data like:

> [ { "RoomId": "f2937f76-05d0-9725-06fc-37cf061a31c6", "FloorNumber": "1", "RoomNumber": "101", "RoomPrefix": "A101",
>   "RoomType": { "$oid": "5b44ca27bb2c563ea4006395" }, "NumberOfBeds":
>   "2", "Available": 0, "BayId": { "$oid": "5be1d5fbbb2c561bb4007837" }
>   }, { "RoomId": "103d89d3-bcdd-351f-6c3c-3b81575b78d2", "FloorNumber":
>   "2", "RoomNumber": "01", "RoomPrefix": "B201", "RoomType": { "$oid":
>   "5b44ca2ebb2c563ea4006396" }, "NumberOfBeds": "3", "Available": "3",
>   "BayId": { "$oid": "5be1d5fbbb2c561bb4007838" } }, { "RoomId":
>   "5677c541-a0b3-fb74-493b-820549c48997", "FloorNumber": "2",
>   "RoomNumber": "201", "RoomCreation": "Manual", "RoomType": { "$oid":
>   "5b44ca27bb2c563ea4006395" }, "NumberOfBeds": "6", "Available": "6",
>   "BayId": { "$oid": "5be1d5fbbb2c561bb4007838" } }, { "RoomId":
>   "1bcf9a01-ca34-5b28-388f-cab05687ff1d", "FloorNumber": "1",
>   "RoomNumber": "103", "RoomCreation": "Manual", "RoomType": { "$oid":
>   "5b44ca27bb2c563ea4006395" }, "NumberOfBeds": "7", "Available": "7",
>   "BayId": { "$oid": "5be1d5fbbb2c561bb4007837" } }, { "RoomId":
>   "5e5d51fd-16e7-4844-2965-98d6afe2d7b4", "FloorNumber": "1",
>   "RoomNumber": "105", "RoomCreation": "Manual", "RoomType": { "$oid":
>   "5b44ca27bb2c563ea4006395" }, "NumberOfBeds": "6", "Available": 4,
>   "BayId": { "$oid": "5be1d5fbbb2c561bb4007837" } }, { "RoomId":
>   "35cd9b4c-15a4-53fd-ba8d-6096883dd1c4", "FloorNumber": "1",
>   "RoomNumber": "106", "RoomCreation": "Manual", "RoomType": { "$oid":
>   "5b44ca27bb2c563ea4006395" }, "NumberOfBeds": "5", "Available": "5",
>   "BayId": { "$oid": "5be1d5fbbb2c561bb4007837" } }, { "RoomId":
>   "cfb4913d-ea28-e52e-94db-36f72601650e", "FloorNumber": "1",
>   "RoomNumber": "104", "RoomCreation": "Manual", "RoomType": { "$oid":
>   "5b44ca27bb2c563ea4006395" }, "NumberOfBeds": "6", "Available": "6",
>   "BayId": { "$oid": "5be1d5fbbb2c561bb4007837" } }, { "RoomId":
>   "64d729fc-fbd5-5834-7820-be467af719f0", "FloorNumber": "1",
>   "RoomNumber": "102", "RoomCreation": "Manual", "RoomType": { "$oid":
>   "5b44ca2ebb2c563ea4006396" }, "NumberOfBeds": "7", "Available": "7",
>   "BayId": { "$oid": "5be1d5fbbb2c561bb4007837" } } ]

Comment: Your use of `array_column` isn't going to work in the way you are expecting here.  It will return an array containing a numeric key with `NumberOfBeds` as the value (i.e. `[0] = "2", [1] = "3"`)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your code here.

Firstly, you have used array_column incorrectly.  With the way you were using it, you'd return an array with a numeric index as the key and the number of rooms as the value.  In addition, you have serialised the object to JSON as a parameter.  This is not necessary - the object is already in the correct state to be used with `array_column`.

The correct way to use it is like so:

```
$RoomsArray = array_column($RoomsDetails, 'NumberOfBeds', 'RoomId');
```

Notice here that `'RoomId'` tells `array_column` to use this column as the key value and the object isn't being serialised to JSON.

Secondly you are using `array_search` to look in the array for the value.  This is incorrect.  By using `array_search` you are looking for the key for the corresponding value you have supplied.  Actually, what you want is to return the value for the key you already have (the room id), like so:

```
$FoundNumberOfBeds = $RoomsArray['f2937f76-05d0-9725-06fc-37cf061a31c6'];
```

By removing the unused lines and modifying the errors, I ended up with the following which correctly returns the number of rooms for the specified `RoomId`:

```
$s = '[ { "RoomId": "f2937f76-05d0-9725-06fc-37cf061a31c6", "FloorNumber": "1", "RoomNumber": "101", "RoomPrefix": "A101", "RoomType": { "$oid": "5b44ca27bb2c563ea4006395" }, "NumberOfBeds": "2", "Available": 0, "BayId": { "$oid": "5be1d5fbbb2c561bb4007837" } } ]';
$RoomsDetails = json_decode($s);

$RoomsArray = array_column($RoomsDetails, 'NumberOfBeds', 'RoomId');
$FoundNumberOfBeds = $RoomsArray['f2937f76-05d0-9725-06fc-37cf061a31c6'];
var_dump($FoundNumberOfBeds);
```

Note that in my example I stripped out all but one of the room entries.  You will of course remove `$s` and `$RoomsDetails` from your code.

Comment: Ehh I misunderstood the question twice.  This is the correct answer. :)

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given '

Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given i

Comment: @NidaAmin that's because Martin used  JSON string for this example purpose. You don't need to decode it as  you get an array from `jsonSerialize`.

Comment: You really should start trying to understand what you're doing and stop just copy&pasting code from SO.

Comment: Now it is throwing Undefined index: f2937f76-05d0-9725-06fc-37cf061a31c6  after removing  json_decode

Comment: Please give answer

Comment: @NidaAmin As I explained to you in my answer, I have provided an example of what you have done wrong and how it can be fixed.  I explicitly said not to leave `$s` and `$RoomDetails` in your code.

Comment: $s = '[ { "RoomId": "f2937f76-05d0-9725-06fc-37cf061a31c6", "FloorNumber": "1", "RoomNumber": "101", "RoomPrefix": "A101", "RoomType": { "$oid": "5b44ca27bb2c563ea4006395" }, "NumberOfBeds": "2", "Available": 0, "BayId": { "$oid": "5be1d5fbbb2c561bb4007837" } } ]';
$RoomsDetails = json_decode($s);

$RoomsArray = array_column($RoomsDetails, 'NumberOfBeds', 'RoomId');
$FoundNumberOfBeds = $RoomsArray['f2937f76-05d0-9725-06fc-37cf061a31c6'];
var_dump($FoundNumberOfBeds);

Comment: If i write exactly what u have provided, it still throws error message Undefined index: f2937f76-05d0-9725-06fc-37cf061a31c6  and Notice: Undefined variable: RoomArray

Comment: @NidaAmin I'm sorry, I don't know how else to help you.  The code I have provided is working for me and addresses all of the faults I found in your code. If you have copied and pasted my example then it will work, but you will need to modify it to integrate it with your existing code, it is just an _example_ of how to solve your problem. And 'Please provide proper code' is not a helpful comment when I already have provided it.

Comment: i will  provide u the exact data of RoomsDetails i.e without RoomsDetails->jsonSerialize(). will u able to help!!!

Comment: object(MongoDB\Model\BSONArray)#46 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(8) { [0]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#24 (1) { ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(8) { ["RoomId"]=> string(36) "f2937f76-05d0-9725-06fc-37cf061a31c6" ["FloorNumber"]=> string(1) "1" ["RoomNumber"]=> string(3) "101" ["RoomPrefix"]=> string(4) "A101" ["RoomType"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#22 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5b44ca27bb2c563ea4006395" } ["NumberOfBeds"]=> string(1) "2" ["Available"]=> int(0) ["BayId"]=> ob................................